# Which executes first? Trigger or rule?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger

Using PostgreSQL.

Had a trigger which does something after delete and made a rule which stopped delete from happening if something will be true.

My question is: will the rule prevent the trigger from occurring as well?

The trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER wypo AFTER INSERT ON "Wyp" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE funk_wyp();
```

The trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funk_wyp() RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
DECLARE
  dodatek real := (SELECT f.cena FROM filmy f WHERE f.ID = NEW.co);
BEGIN
    UPDATE "zyskiklient" 
       SET "ile" = ile + dodatek 
    WHERE kto = NEW.kto; 
    UPDATE "istotnoscklienta" 
       SET "poziom" = (SELECT poziom(NEW."kto")) 
    WHERE "kto" = NEW.kto;
RETURN NEW;
END; 
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE zasada_delete_konto 
  AS ON DELETE TO "konto" 
WHERE konto_zwrocone(OLD."ID") = FALSE 
DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can consider a rule as transforming the command being executed, whereas a trigger is altering the data itself. (Note that this is a simplification! Spend some time reading the documentation for [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) and [`CREATE RULE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html) rather than trusting some random internet guy.)

So you can define a rule that is invoked when PostgreSQL sees a certain command, and transforms that command into something that would not invoke the trigger.

Take for instance a rule defined as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE dont_insert AS
ON INSERT TO xyz.items
DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

And a trigger defined as such:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_with_func BEFORE INSERT
ON xyz.items FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE xyz.row_update_func();
```

Attempting to do an insert will not invoke `row_update_func()`, even if the trigger is defined as `BEFORE INSERT`, because the rule is modifying the command itself; after the command is re-evaluated, it's no longer doing anything, and the trigger no longer applies.

Obviously your rule does not *need to be* defined with `INSTEAD OF`, and in that case, your rule and your trigger could both apply.

With specific regard to *your* code, it's hard to say without knowing the definition of `konto_zwrocone`, but it doesn't look like it since your trigger and rule are defined for different operations on different tables.

Answer (score 4):

[@Chris provides an excellent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126438/3684) for the question in the title.

Your question itself is inconsistent in multiple places, talking about a trigger "after delete", but showing a trigger `AFTER INSERT`. Rule and trigger are on different tables and your trigger function is needlessly convoluted. A clean way could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funk_wyp()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE zyskiklient z
   SET    ile = z.ile + f.cena      -- no separate query 
   FROM   filmy f
   WHERE  f.id = NEW.co             -- see below!
   AND    z.kto = NEW.kto;

   UPDATE istotnoscklienta
   SET    poziom = poziom(NEW.kto)  -- no subselect
   WHERE  kto = NEW.kto;

   RETURN NEW;  -- ?!?
END
$func$;
```

Note a subtle difference: *my* first `UPDATE` will do nothing if no row for `f.id = NEW.co` is found - as opposed to your original which will update anyway and set the column to `NULL`. Typically, you would want the behavior of my version.

But it still wouldn't make sense to `RETURN NEW` in a trigger `AFTER INSERT` (or `AFTER DELETE`). [The manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an
> operation, and so they can return `NULL`.

[... and here:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> ... and `DELETE` triggers cannot refer to `NEW`.

Start by reading the manual on [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html),  [PL/pgSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), [trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Note that I edited the title, to reflect the content of the question as I interpreted it.